# How to correct the incomplete Polygon geometry and insert in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

When run the below code I get the error *(3037, 'Invalid GIS data provided to function st_polyfromtext')*. I saw other post with similar error but cannot find answer for this particular situation!

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=, user="", passwd="", db="db", charset="utf8")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE `db`.`table` ("
"`ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
"`X_Center` DOUBLE NULL,"
"`Y_Center` DOUBLE NULL,"
"`geometry` POLYGON NOT NULL,"
"PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));")

with open("file.csv",encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
     for row in reader:
       sql_statement = "INSERT INTO table(X_Center,Y_Center,geometry) VALUES (%s, %s, ST_PolyFromText(%s,0))"
       cur = conn.cursor()
       param = [(row['X_Center'], row['Y_Center'], row['geometry']))]
       cur.executemany(sql_statement,param)
       conn.escape_string(sql_statement)
       conn.commit()
```

The polygon files "file.csv" has both complete values and incomplete values polygon values.

**How can I get a complete polygon values and insert it into MySQL database ?**

[image: table of the Polygon]

Comment: Why not provide "complete" values?

Comment: I added a link to my csv file @Nico

Comment: That does not solve my question - if you try to import incomplete data, why don't you provide ways to correct them, either through some pre-processing or through completing it?

Comment: Sorry now I understand !! Yes I am finding ways to do that , once I edit and convert the .shp to .csv the data is being incomplete.

Comment: What is in `%s`? And please don't say "look at the picture" - We are talking about **text**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In your case an MCVE is a one-liner `SELECT ST_PolyFromText(???, 0)`. Just fill in `???`. And the server version.

Answer (score 0):

**I will answer my own question.**

I thought the error was due to the polygon values being incomplete but it turns out be the polygon values was not incomplete , since the polygon value is large excel doesn't show the full values, hence shows half values only.

The actual error was apparently in my geometry column where the Polygon file has 3 values X, Y and Z. When given command "ST_PolyFromText", I assumed that it identifies only X and Y values and fails to identify Z and hence throws the error "3037,Invalid GIS data provided to function ST_PolyFromText". With the help of this stack answer, I converted my geometry column from [3D to 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35211729/10546341). Then when used the above code to insert the polygon values , it was successfully inserted into the database.